# Extension for OmniSharp

Tags: visual-studio-code, omnisharp

Is there any way to get an extension point in [omnisharp-roslyn](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn)?
I see that omnisharp.exe has the "--plugin" argument, but the digging in the source code did not give me an answer: how to use this argument. 
I need a way to include my assemblies in mef composition, so I can import Roslyn and OmniSharp services and export my ICodeActionProvider.

Answer (score 0):

Plugins/extensions are a work in progress for the omnisharp-roslyn project.

There's an open [PR](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/pull/640) for it.